# TypeError: Recaptcha is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, recaptcha

Suddenly my app stopped compiling due to this TypeError: Recaptcha is not a constructor.

```
    recaptchaConfig() {
        this.recaptcha = new Recaptcha(
            config.service.recaptcha.client_key,
            config.service.recaptcha.secret_key , 
            {...config.service.recaptcha.options}
        );
    }
```

It was working just fine, and now I don't know what caused it.
https://github.com/arya107/AskArya-Node.js-Vue.js/blob/master/Server/app/http/controllers/controller.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tried your code and with:

```
var Recaptcha = require('express-recaptcha').Recaptcha;
```

got the sam exception, but if you try:

```
var Recaptcha = require('express-recaptcha').RecaptchaV3;
```

it works, try it.

Comment: it now starts, but when I try to sign in the app, it gives me this error: callback is required
            
Error: callback is required

Comment: then you need this: 
`var recaptcha = new Recaptcha('SITE_KEY', 'SECRET_KEY',{callback:'cb'});`

Comment: `this.recaptcha = new Recaptcha(
            config.service.recaptcha.client_key,
            config.service.recaptcha.secret_key , 
            {...config.service.recaptcha.options}
        );` there, you see third argument is object (options), send your callback function inside third arg

Comment: you need something like 
`this.recaptcha = new Recaptcha( config.service.recaptcha.client_key, config.service.recaptcha.secret_key , {callback: function() {....your_function_code}} );`
I am missing the context, but try something like that, maybe docs can help https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-recaptcha